# How to substitute dashes with dots in every element of character vector in R?

Tags: regex, r, character, stringi

Is there an easy way to substitute dashes with dots in every element of character vector in R?

```
input
c("T-A-B", "C-L1")
output
c("T.A.B", "C.L1")
```

Was looking for help in `stringi` package but couldn't find answer.
There is `stri_substitute` function but I don't know how to use this.

Comment: usually use `gsub` but in this case `make.names(c("T-A-B", "C-L1"))`

Comment: I like the `make.names` usage here. Very refreshing. If you want a `stringi` solution, try `stri_replace_all_fixed(c("T-A-B", "C-L1"), "-", ".")`

Comment: `make.names` is indeed insane!

Comment: @DavidArenburg i like your answer :) please post it as an aswer and I'll flag it

Answer (score 6):

Base `R` like this (gsub vectorized thanks to @docendo):

```
> gsub("-",".",c("T-A-B", "C-L1"))
[1] "T.A.B" "C.L1"
```

Or with `stringr`:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_replace_all( c("T-A-B", "C-L1"),"-",".")
[1] "T.A.B" "C.L1"
```